# Как вывести сообщение о неверном формате через через MessageBox.Show?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать, чтобы выводило ошибку через `MessageBox.Show` с текстом:

> Неверный формат x/y/z

Сейчас у меня программа перестает работать если ввести буквы. Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            double y = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            double z = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            double s = Math.Pow(y, Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x), 1 / 3)) + Math.Pow(Math.Cos(y), 3) * (Math.Abs(x - y) *
                        (1 + ((Math.Pow(Math.Sin(z), 2)) / (Math.Sqrt(x + y)))) / (Math.Exp(Math.Abs(x - y)) + x / 2));
            s = Math.Round(s, 2);
            textBox4.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox4.Text = s.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для ввода чисел лучше использовать NumericUpDown вместо TextBox.

Comment: У меня задания использовать именно TextBox

Comment: Используйте события [валидации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Для моего уровня с#, это очень сложно реализовать, к сожалению

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас может происходить Exception при конвертировании в строке `double x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);`

Вы можете либо перехватить это исключение, написав что то вроде

```
    double x=0;
    try{
        x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        MessageBox.Show($"Не могу сконвертировать {textBox1.Text} в число");
    }
```

либо использовать метод TryParse:

```
    double x=0;
    bool cnvRez = Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x);
    if (!cnvRez)
        MessageBox.Show($"Не могу сконвертировать {textBox1.Text} в число");
```

Comment: В первом случае у меня, где строка "double s = ...", показывает что переменные не существуют. Во втором случае, в строке " bool cnvRez = Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, ref x);" переменная х подсвечивается красным. Подскажите почему так получается

Comment: Справедливое замечание... Писал в спешке, опечатался пару раз - сейчас поправил. Впротчем, совет Александра Петрова - использовать события валидации - вообще, более правильный. Мой подход - это, скорее, удобный костыль

Comment: Подставил код, который во втором случае и все работает. Спасибо!!!

Comment: Смысл делать `catch (Exception ex)`, если `ex` никак не используется? Можно проще написать либо `catch (Exception)`, либо просто `catch`.